# flexbox child margin right doesn't applied

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I want to make equal gap for the children of flexbox. I used margin-right zero for each child, then applied the margin right back on the last child. But the margin right somehow doesn't applied. You can see after you scrolled to the end of the child.

see demo below

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
  background: pink;
  width: 80px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.item {
  min-width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: black;
  margin: 8px;
  margin-right: 0;
}

.item:last-child {
  margin-right: 4px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

add another parent div and give overflow for parent div. For `.flex` class apply `display:inline-flex;` then it will works

```
.flex-parent{
  overflow: auto;
  width: 80px;
}
.flex {
  display: flex;
  background: pink;
  min-width:100%;
  float:left;
}
```

```css
.flex-parent{
  overflow: auto;
  width: 80px;
}
.flex {
  display: inline-flex;
  background: pink;
  /*min-width:100%;
  float:left;*/
}

.item {
  min-width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: black;
  margin: 8px;
  margin-right: 0;
}

.item:last-child {
  margin-right: 4px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-parent">
 <div class="flex">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: inline-flex better than combining float and flex

Comment: @TemaniAfif I tried but it's not worked that's why I added float

Comment: @TemaniAfif yeah it's working, I thought you tried without parent div. Okay I will modify the answer

Answer (score 0):

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
  background: pink;
  width: 200px;
  overflow: auto;
justify-content: space-between;
}

.item {
  min-width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```